# How to check the continue classes in set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 items in a list with this kind of structure where any item can have active class depending on some situations and this active class will add on item when user click on it. I want to get the number of set of 3 continue active classes. in the given example the 3 continue active classes are 2 times on items 4,5,6 and 8,9,10.
So the output should be 2 only.

How to achieve this.
I know I can get the total number of Active classes just by getting its length, but how to get if its how many times in continuity?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let totalActivce = $('.active').length;
  console.log(totalActivce);
});
```

```css
.active {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="active">item1 </li>  
<li>item2 </li>  
<li>item3 </li>  
<li class="active">item4 </li>  
<li class="active">item5 </li>  
<li class="active">item6 </li>  
<li>item7 </li>  
<li  class="active">item8 </li>  
<li  class="active">item9 </li> 
<li  class="active">item10 </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the elements between your first element with the class `active` and the next you can use `$('.active:first').nextUntil(".active")`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let totalActivce = $('.active:first').nextUntil(".active").length;
  console.log(totalActivce);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">item1 </li>
  <li>item2 </li>
  <li>item3 </li>
  <li class="active">item4 </li>
  <li class="active">item5 </li>
  <li class="active">item6 </li>
  <li>item7 </li>
  <li class="active">item8 </li>
  <li class="active">item9 </li>
  <li class="active">item10 </li>
</ul>
```

**Demo 2**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var f = 0;
  $("ul li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(".active") && $(this).nextUntil(':not(.active)').addBack().length == 3) {
      f++;
    }
  });
  console.log(f);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">item1 </li>
  <li>item2 </li>
  <li>item3 </li>
  <li class="active">item4 </li>
  <li class="active">item5 </li>
  <li class="active">item6 </li>
  <li>item7 </li>
  <li class="active">item8 </li>
  <li class="active">item9 </li>
  <li class="active">item10 </li>
</ul>
```

**Demo 3**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var f = 0;
  var s = 1;
  $("ul li").each(function(i) {
    if (s <= i) {
      if ($(this).is(".active") && $(this).nextUntil(':not(.active)').addBack().length >= 3) {
        s = s + 3;
        f++;
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(f);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>item1 </li>
  <li class="active">item2 </li>
  <li class="active">item3 </li>
  <li class="active">item4 </li>
  <li class="active">item5 </li>
  <li class="active">item6 </li>
  <li class="active">item7 </li>
  <li class="active">item8 </li>
  <li class="active">item9 </li>
  <li class="active">item10 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello Carsten,

As I told in the question that any item can have active class. so Maybe all of them have active, or first will not have active and then last 9 have active and in both the situations this approach will not work.

Comment: @Smartestdumb Take a look at demo 2

Comment: I think you are not getting the requirement or maybe I am not able to clarify it properly.
have a look at this screen shot, https://prnt.sc/10oxiq7
the f value should be here 3, because we have 3 sets of active class, while your code is giving output 0

Comment: @Smartestdumb in the screenshot how is there 3 sets of active class? I see 9 active in a row? Is a set 3x active in a row?

Comment: @Smartestdumb Look at demo2 now.

Comment: every 3 continue active makes a set of 1. so 9 continue active means 3 sets of actives.

Comment: @Smartestdumb try demo3

Answer (score 0):

You can loop your elements and check if previous elements where active:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let totalActivce = $('.active').length;
  let sets = 0;
  let isPreviousActive = 0;
  console.log(totalActivce);

  $('ul li').each(function() {
    let isActive = $(this).is('.active');

    if (isActive) {
      isPreviousActive++;

      if (isPreviousActive == 2) {
        sets++;
      }
    }

    if (!isActive) {
      isPreviousActive = 0;
    }
  });

  console.log(sets);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">item1 </li>
  <li>item2 </li>
  <li>item3 </li>
  <li class="active">item4 </li>
  <li class="active">item5 </li>
  <li class="active">item6 </li>
  <li>item7 </li>
  <li class="active">item8 </li>
  <li class="active">item9 </li>
  <li class="active">item10 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello Justinas,
In this approach, if I have active on last 9 items then it will only giving me one, while it should give me 3, because we have 3 sets of 3 continue active classes.